# ActionBar: 1 item visible while rest in overflow regardless of room

Tags: android

I've played with all the showAsAction values to no avail.

I basically just want the delete button visible while the Exit will go into the overflow (3 dots). I'll be adding more to the overflow one but I'd like to know how to force Exit into it.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_delete"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_delete"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_exit"
      android:title="Exit"
      android:showAsAction="collapseActionView" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `android:showAsAction="never"` to force an action item into the overflow.

Comment: Does the AVD not show the overflow when started? The delete is there but there's no overflow menu next to it.

Comment: @Denis: Your AVD is probably set up to emulate a device with a physical MENU button, in which case the overflow does not show the dots. However, pressing MENU will bring up the menu. To have an emulator without a MENU button, add "Hardware Back/Home keys" to your Hardware: section of the AVD configuration, set to "no".

Comment: So on the galaxy nexus it would look like this? http://isozial.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/google_play_galaxy_nexus1.png

Comment: @Denis: Yes. On the Nexus S, with ICS, you would not see the dots, but the user would press the MENU button to bring up the menu, as they did with Android 2.3.