# Explicitly putting item in overflow menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Can I explicitly put an icon of action bar in overflow menu even if there is space in the action bar itself? I have an "about" menu item, which really isn't that crucial to the app so I thought about putting it in overflow, or maybe I should go ahead and display it anyway

Comment: is this for the AppCompat ActionBar or regular ActionBar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include `namespace:showAsAction="never"` in your XML defining the menu item.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195630/actionbar-1-item-visible-while-rest-in-overflow-regardless-of-room Check that out. It might be your AVD if you're using one.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: `YES`

`Code` answer:

Declare as many `int` values as you need, like this:

```
public static final int MENU_SETTINGS = Menu.FIRST;
public static final int MENU_SETTINGS = Menu.FIRST+1;
public static final int MENU_SETTINGS = Menu.FIRST+2;
```

Then in `onCreateOptionsMenu` add the value you want to show in the overflow menu.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_SETTINGS, Menu.NONE, "Settings");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_ONE, Menu.NONE, "Other_1");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_TWO, Menu.NONE, "Other_2");
    return true;
}
```

Then to retrieve which one has been selected use:

```
/**
 * Listener
 */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case MENU_SETTINGS: {
            //YOUR CODE
        }
        case MENU_ONE: {
            //YOUR CODE
        }
        case MENU_TWO: {
            //YOUR CODE
        }
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```